# Tooltip changes position on few images

Tags: html, css, image, tooltip

I am building a website and ran into another problem with my code. 
I have tooltips for a huge number of images so that when you hover over them you see information in the tooltip ( which is also an image)

My Problem is that when I hover the first few images they display the tooltip different then the rest of them.

My code looks like this:

```
.playertooltipimg{
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}
.playertooltipimg {
 z-index: 100000;
}
a.tooltips {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;

}
a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
  border: 5px solid white;
  left:-80.15em;

  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  left:-51.15em;
  top: -0.2em;


  visibility: visible;

  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;


  z-index: 999;
}
```

I think it's hard to understand what I mean which is why i created this jfiddle:

BUT you have to adjust the size of the window so that the 2 white boxes can be next to each other (in a row)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkQLV/

I know it's a lot of code, I can't figure out why it is doing this, since every other images except the first few display the tooltip correctly

Comment: You have some very large values in your positioning `(left:-80.15em;)`...why?

Comment: I cant figure out how to position the Tooltip otherwise. I thought pixels would make problems with different resolutions

Comment: ems are still pixels...It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: i thought em's are measured by the font-size, well ok. But I need a way to position my tooltip in the other white box.

Comment: Then I think you are going about this the wrong way. I don't think a tooltip is what you are after.

Comment: What do you think of? I want a way of displaying content on a hover.

Comment: It sounds to me as though you want some sort of gallery with thumbnails that show larger pictures somewhere else...that's not really a tooltip kind of thing.

Comment: http://demosthenes.info/blog/58/CSS-and-Images-Simple-Roll-over-Image-Gallery

Comment: Well the smaller pictures are Links so I will want people to click on them. But before they click they learn more about each invdiual picture with a bigger picture.

Comment: That seems okay.. But It doesnt give me much freedom positionin the seperate elements

Comment: its basicly the same thing. Just written a bit differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the use of `inline` and `relative` styles for the `a` (which is the container of the preview item). `inline` style makes the absolute positioning of the inner `span` a little strange, you can see that all the items on the second row seem to work OK, it happens only to the items on the first row (except the last item). However if you set `display:inline-block` for the `a` elements, you'll see that hovering on all the items won't work now, the popped-up tooltip has always the same offset (on the left side) from the `a` element (which you hover on). That's because you set `position:relative` for the `a` elements. So all the offsets (`left` and `top`) of the `span`s (which you set to some fixed values relative to font-size with `em` unit) will be compared against the hovered `a` element's position. To fix this issue, you have to choose the same element for all the items against which the offsets are set. The most suitable item is exactly the div `#playersbig` which contains all the items. To choose that div as the containing block of the inner `span` elements (in each item), you have to set its `position` to `relative` (which you've already done) **but** you have to remove the `position:relative` applied on the `a` elements.

Another note is that you should use `right` property to position your tooltip (`span` element), in the hidden state the `right` is ***about*** `200%` (because your 2 divs `#championsbig` and `#playersbig` have the same width) while in the shown state, the `right` should be ***about*** `100%`. The exact values of `right` depend on the padding/space width between your 2 divs `#championsbig` and `#playersbig`, looks like it's about `4px` in your case). You can also use `calc` function to set the exact value **but** it's not supported by some old versions of browsers (especially the so-called **IE**), so I just use `201%` and `101%` respectively in the demo (because the width is `400px`). If the `width` is fixed at `400px`, you can also calculate the exact values for `right` yourself such as `804px` and `404px` instead of `201%` and `101%`.

**CSS**:

```
a.tooltips {  
  /* use this to have the expected absolute positioning 
     instead of the unexpected behavior when using inline style */
  display: inline-block;  
}

a.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
  border: 5px solid white;
  top:0;
  /* use right instead of left, this will hide the tooltip initially */
  right:201%;  
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
}

a:hover.tooltips span {
  position: absolute;
  /* this will show the tooltip on hovering */
  right:101%;  
  visibility: visible;  
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999; 
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ZkQLV/1/)

Comment: I understand and thank you for your solution. But a question about the use of inline. I used it because inline-block adds this weird spacing which I can't get to remove except using negative margin values which would be kind of odd.          So this there a way of using inline-block, but not having the weird spacing between the smaller images. IN your Demo the spacing is farely obvious

Comment: @user3648229 the space (between the inline-block elements) is always rendered (even you use a line-break to separate the elements). To fix this issue, there are some ways, the first is to write all the element tags adjacently without any space (even a line-break between them, such as `<a>...</a><a>...</a>...` like in this [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ZkQLV/2/). Another quick fix is to use `float:left` for your `a` elements like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ZkQLV/3/)